# How do I handle branches of code before it gets too messy?

Tags: php, coding-style, standards

So my actual question is, if I have multiple if-elseif cases looking for 1 right match, but all the cases got alot of the same code but some cases are a little diffrent, which way is most efficient?

Sorting by roles and repeating code?

```
$user_role = 2;

if ($user_role === 1) {
  codeMethod1();
  codeMethod2();
} elseif ($user_role === 2) {
  codeMethod1();
  codeMethod2();
  codeMethod3();
} elseif ($user_role === 3) {
  codeMethod2();
  codeMethod3();
}
```

or, sorting by code/process and make huge if statements?

```
$user_role = 2;

if ($user_role === 1 || 2) {
  codeMethod1();
} 

codeMethod2();

if ($user_role === 2 || 3) {
  codeMethod3();
}
```

I realise that for some people this is a dumb question, because they already got it all figured out. I'm new to programming and I just want to get it right from the start. I don't want to ruin my program or ruin it for people who might have to fix my code.

**UPDATE**

Scenario for question clarification:

When a user enters my site, I identify them as 1 of 5 categories.
Some users will get the same treatment with some variations while others will get wildly diffrent treatments.
There is about 20 different methods, where some users will use them all and others will use few.

So, is is better and/or more efficient to list the methods each category needs, even though alot of the code will look the same.

Example:

```
$user_role = getCurrentUserRole();

switch ($user_role) {
  case 1:
    (uses method1() to method10())
    break;

  case 2:
    (uses method5() to method15())
    break;

  case 3:
    (uses method10() to method20())
    break

  case 4:
    (uses method1() to method20())
    break

  case 5:
    method1();
    method4();
    method8();
    method15();
    method20();
}
```

OR, is it better to list every method and use if statements to see if the `$user_role` needs it?

Example:

```
$user_role = getCurrentUserRole();

switch ($user_role) {
  // Check for method1
  case (1 || 4) {
    method1();
  }

  // Check for method2
  case (1 || 4) {
    method2();
  }

  ... skip ...

  // Check for method5
  case (1 || 2 || 4) {
    method5();
  }

  .. Continue checking role permission for each method ..
}
```

Please ignore my bad english, and tell me to elaborate if you don't get my question.

Comment: Use `switch` instead of multiple if else as you compare Only one value: $user_role

Comment: Switch to a switch when you can. It makes code clean-er. Other than that, if you must have them, get a good IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Group functions under your user roles functions and simply call those functions for particular user role.

```
$user_role = 2;

switch($user_role){
    case 1:
        userRole1(); 
        break;

    case 2:
       userRole2();
       break;

    case 3:
      userRole3();
      break;
}

function userRole1(){
        codeMethod1();
        codeMethod2();
}
function userRole2(){
       codeMethod1();
       codeMethod2();
       codeMethod3();
}
function userRole3(){
      codeMethod2();
      codeMethod3(); 
}
```

Comment: OP did ask about deduplication within the code blocks, not for an alternative comparison syntax.

Comment: I like it, but it seems like you just moved the duplication somewhere else, isn't functions just for recalling large portions of code?

Comment: @guestedForAnwser , yes it will obviously happen but at least you have Group of N number of function at one place and you can simply call  `userRole1()` in order to call other functions. See, you must use Object oriented programming using class which promotes reusability. You need to modify it, as its not in your question. Please modify the code in OOP way.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a roles→features association.

But in your case it might be more appropriate to associate role numbers to possible functions with a simple map:

```
$role_funcs = [
    "method1" => [ 1, 2,        ],
    "method2" => [ 1, 2, 3,    5],
    "method3" => [       3,    5],
    "method4" => [ 1,    3, 4,  ],
    // …
    "method9" => [    2, 3,    5],
];
```

Which gives a compact overview on which function blocks will be run for which user class. And it's pretty trivial to utilize:

```
foreach ($role_funcs as $callback=>$for_roles) {
    if (in_array($user_role, $for_roles)) {
        $callback();
    }
}
```

Now that only works of course if you really have them all available as functions. (Otherwise you might even want to aim higher, wrap users and roles into objects, to utilize one of the dispatcher patterns implicitly.)